# How can I redirect multiple domains to external ones using no backend in Traefik v1.x?

Tags: redirect, networking, traefik

I would like to redirect from `domain1.com`, `domain2.com`, `domain50.com` to `external.com` but without a backend (just 301 redirection). 
I did heard it's possible via some entrypoint regex but I have many domains that I want to redirect to specific ones.

References:

- [PR #178: Add multiple entry points support](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/178)
- [Issue #723: Multiple entry regex redirects](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/723)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Traefik v1.x doesn't support multiple redirections without backend I have solved adding this hack that solved my issue partially.

I have done basically via one redirection regex using one frontend + fake backend for the *first group* and then for *the second one* just one redirection at the entrypoint level because entrypoint also supports redirection based on regex.

Here the complete config which worked for me:

```toml
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
    permanent = true

[entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.redirect]
      # Group 1
      regex = "https://(www.)?(d1.com|d2.com|d3.com)(.+)?"
      replacement = "https://www.x1.com$3"
      permanent = true
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[file]
watch = true

[backends]
  [backends.fake]
    [backends.fake.servers.s1]
      url = "http://1.2.3.4"

[frontends]
  [frontends.r2]
    entryPoints = ["https"]
    backend = "fake"
    [frontends.r2.redirect]
      # Group 2
      regex = "https://(www.)?(d4.com|d5.com|d6.com)(.+)?"
      replacement = "https://www.x2.com$3"
      permanent = false
```

The complete discussion about this can be found in official Traefik forum:
[External domain redirection without backend proxy using Traefik v1.x](https://community.containo.us/t/external-domain-redirection-without-backend-proxy-using-traefik-v1-x/836/)

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      regex = "^http://localhost/(.*)"
      replacement = "http://mydomain/$1"
```

Comment: Solve partially my issue, I want to just redirect groups of domains to specific ones.
More info here https://community.containo.us/t/external-domain-redirection-without-backend-proxy-using-traefik-v1-x/836

Comment: sorry, I have updated the title because was very generic.

Comment: I see - I think this is currently not possible with Traefik. Why not use nginx?